# Как узнать из какого фрагмента пользователь перешёл на другой фрагмент?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, kotlin

Есть 3 фрагмента: A-B-C.

В фрагмент C можно перейти из фрагмента B, также в фрагмент C можно перейти из A.

Какая наилучшая практика позволяет отслеживать(узнавать надо в фрагменте C) из какого фрагмента был осуществлен переход?

Comment: Просто передай параметр fragment_id из одного фрагмента во второй. В фрагменте C можно его будет прочитать.

Comment: @iamtihonov ну можно юзать bundle, интересны другие решения )))

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой вариант:

```
private String getCallerFragment(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    return fm.getBackStackEntryAt(count - 2).getName();
}
```